# Other Linker Flags set to -ObjC

Tags: ios, objective-c, linker-errors

I have included Other Linker Flags set to -ObjC in my Build Settings as I would like to use a framework that requires this (https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

However after adding this flag I get linker errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
```

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKProductsRequest", referenced from:

```
  objc-class-ref in Parse(PFPurchase.o)
```

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKPayment", referenced from:

```
  objc-class-ref in Parse(PFPurchase.o)
```

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_SKPaymentQueue", referenced from:

```
  objc-class-ref in Parse(PFPurchase.o)

  objc-class-ref in Parse(PFPaymentTransactionObserver.o)
```

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Removing the -ObjC linker flag and the project builds again without errors. Any ideas of the cause? Thanks.

Comment: May i know your xCode, deployment target version and device ios Version?

Answer (score 19):

You need to add `StoreKit.framework`.

Version **1.0.62** of the **Parse iOS SDK** introduced **In-App Purchases**. This requires **`StoreKit.framework`** to be added to existing Parse iOS projects, even if IAP is not being used.

Do this:

1. Select your project
2. Select your target
3. Select Build Phases
4. In Link Binaries with Libraries, click +
5. Search for StoreKit and Add

Then import the framework to your project:

```
#import "StoreKit/StoreKit.h"
```

See the same error in this [Parse community link](https://parse.com/questions/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-i386-objcclassskpayment).

Answer (score 6):

add `Storekit` framework in your project and use this statement where you use write code for In App Purchage

```
#import "StoreKit/StoreKit.h"
```

Comment: The `#import` is superfluous if IAP is unused (and has nothing to do with the **linker** error anyway).